# SAPUI5 blocklayout form

Tags: xml, sapui5

I want to use block layout in SAPUI5 to create a form but I have a problem, I want show the label text and combobox with label in above combobox but I can't. I want to position the combobox and label just like the label and input field (the input below the label). But the combobox is placed just beside the label. How do I fix this problem?

Code:

```
        <Panel>
            <content>
                <l:VerticalLayout id="containerLayout" width="100%">
                    <l:BlockLayout id="BlockLayout" background="{/selectedBackground}">
                        <l:BlockLayoutRow accentCells="Accent0">
                            <l:BlockLayoutCell width="3">
                                <Text text="Alamat" />
                                <ComboBox />
                            </l:BlockLayoutCell>
                        </l:BlockLayoutRow>

                        <l:BlockLayoutRow accentCells="Accent1">
                            <l:BlockLayoutCell id="Accent1" width="2">
                                <Text text="Name" />
                                <Input />
                            </l:BlockLayoutCell>
                            <l:BlockLayoutCell>
                                <Text text="Alamat" />
                                <Input showValueHelp="true"/>
                            </l:BlockLayoutCell>
                            <l:BlockLayoutCell titleAlignment="End">
                                <Text text="HP" />
                                <Input />
                            </l:BlockLayoutCell>
                        </l:BlockLayoutRow>

                        <l:BlockLayoutRow>
                            <l:BlockLayoutCell id="Accent2" width="2">
                                <Text text="Name" />
                                <Input />
                            </l:BlockLayoutCell>
                            <l:BlockLayoutCell>
                                <Text text="Alamat" />
                                <Input />
                            </l:BlockLayoutCell>
                            <l:BlockLayoutCell titleAlignment="End">
                                <Text text="HP" />
                                <Input />
                            </l:BlockLayoutCell>                                    
                        </l:BlockLayoutRow>
                    </l:BlockLayout>
                </l:VerticalLayout>
            </content>
        </Panel>
```

[image: Block Layout]

Answer (score 0):

You could simple place both the label and the combobox within a Vertical Layout. This would place the Combobox below the label.

```
<Panel>
        <content>
            <l:VerticalLayout id="containerLayout" width="100%">
                <l:BlockLayout id="BlockLayout" background="{/selectedBackground}">
                    <l:BlockLayoutRow accentCells="Accent0">
                        <l:BlockLayoutCell width="3">
                            <l:VerticalLayout>
                                <Text text="Alamat" />
                                <ComboBox />
                            </l:VerticalLayout> 
                        </l:BlockLayoutCell>
                    </l:BlockLayoutRow>
...
...
</Panel>
```